# how write this access code to sqlite code

Tags: database, sqlite, ms-access

SELECT Person.Person_id, Person.name, Person.last_name, ( select sum(debt.paye) from debt where debt.person_id= Person.Person_id) AS sum_pay, ( select sum(debt.not_paye) from debt where credit.person_id= Person.Person_id) AS sum_not_pay, **[sum_pay]-[sum_non_pay] AS def**
FROM Person;

Comment: What is your question? What have you already tried? What errors are you encountering?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select Person.Person_id, Person.name, Person.last_name,sum_pay,sum_non_pay, sum_pay-sum_non_pay as def 
from 
(
SELECT Person.Person_id, Person.name, Person.last_name, ( select sum(credit.paye) from credit where credit.person_id= Person.Person_id) AS sum_pay, ( select sum(credit.non_paye) from credit where credit.person_id= Person.Person_id) AS sum_non_pay
from person
)
```